# Extract text in string from column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I return column `pathToFolder` but only containing the letters `hello3\heeello4`?

```
create table #testing(pathToFolder varchar(200) )

insert into #testing values
('c:\hello\hello2\hello3\heeello4\hello5'), 
('c:\hi\hi2\hi3\hiii4\hi5')

select pathToFolder from #testing;
```

I need to return `hello3\heeello4` and `hi3\hiii4` in the select statement.

Comment: `^[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\([^\\]+\\[^\\]+)` and your desired result will be in $1. https://regex101.com/r/9W5U1W/1

Comment: Ditto if you want to use `^(?:[^\\]+\\){3}([^\\]+\\[^\\]+)` instead

Comment: @MonkeyZeus does that work in T-SQL?

Comment: Can you explain your "need to print" and why it conflicts with the title of your question? Perhaps you really do mean _forth_ rather than _fourth_.

Comment: @HABO: see update. Yes my mistake I do not want to print I need to return a result set, which I actually need to in an insert into....

Comment: Work with me on this. What text is _between_ the third and fourth backslash in `'c:\hello\hello2\hello3\heeello4\hello5'`? By my reckoning it's `'hello3'`.

Comment: @HABO: see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @count int = 0,
       @position1 int = 0,
       @position2 int = 0,
       @string1 varchar(50) = 'c:\hello\hello2\hello3\heeello4\hello5',
       @string2 varchar(50) = 'c:\hi\hi2\hi3\hiii4\hi5'

while (@count < 4)
begin
    set @position1 = cast( CHARINDEX('\', @string1, @position1) as int) + 1
    set @position2 = cast( CHARINDEX('\', @string2, @position2) as int) + 1
    set @count = @count + 1
end

set @string1 = (select right(@string1, @position1 -2))
set @string2 = (select right(@string2, @position2 -2))

while (@count < 7)
begin
    set @position1 = cast( CHARINDEX('\', @string1, @position1) as int) + 1
    set @position2 = cast( CHARINDEX('\', @string2, @position2) as int) + 1
    set @count = @count + 1
end

set @string1 = (select left(@string1, @position1 -2))
set @string2 = (select left(@string2, @position2 -2))
select @string1, @string2
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to take `hello3\heeello4`. Right now it prints `heeello4\hello5`. Also i need to use it on a column in a select statement...This was not part of the question I know...

Comment: Ok, I can update it.  Change to `@count < 4`.  Also, are you wanting \hello5 to print or do you want to stop at hello4?

Comment: Edits above.  There might be a cleaner way to do this but this will definitely get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Essentially you can use the same loops since you're drilling into the same level of both paths.  If you had a need to drill into a different level, you would have to recreate the query again for the new path.  I have edited the answer to fit your new needs.

Answer (score 0):

The question has finally been edited down to a classic "I have"/"I need" with no indication of how the minimal sample data relates to the desired result. What it does offer is, at best, misleading: "but only containing the letters `hello3\heeello4`".

So it goes. The following code does stuff that might be the stuff that is wanted. It also meets the reclusive "i need to use it on a column in a select statement" requirement. There is, as of this time, no requirement that it not burst into flames if the path doesn't contain enough directories.

```
with HelpVampire as (
  select Path,
    CharIndex( '\', Path ) as ReverseSolidus1Position,
    CharIndex( '\', Path, CharIndex( '\', Path ) + 1 ) as ReverseSolidus2Position,
    CharIndex( '\', Path, CharIndex( '\', Path, CharIndex( '\', Path ) + 1 ) + 1 ) as ReverseSolidus3Position,
    Substring( Path, CharIndex( '\', Path, CharIndex( '\', Path, CharIndex( '\', Path ) + 1 ) + 1 ) + 1, 255 ) as Remainder
    from ( values
      ( 'c:\hello\hello2\hello3\heeello4\hello5' ), ( 'c:\hi\hi2\hi3\hiii4\hi5' )
      ) as Samples ( Path ) )
  select *,
    CharIndex( '\', Remainder ) as PerverseSolidus1Position,
    Substring( Remainder, CharIndex( '\', Remainder ) + 1, 255 ) as ASubstringFromThePath
    from HelpVampire;
```